# Qt Creator adding mqtt library

Tags: c++, qt, mqtt

Working on Win 10 with QT Creator 4.3.1
Trying to add a library to my qt project via the GUI. In specific the qtmqtt library.

right click on project -> "Add library..." and simply nothing happens.

Anybody else having this problem?

Seems like I am to stupid to add a library directory via the .pro file. Googled for hours but cant get my head around it. So I really need the GUI solution to be working.

Comment: Googled **for hours**? :) Here you go: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

Comment: Well ok I googled for some time at least but didnt understand to much. Lets put it this way. Thanks for the link anyway, seems like I have to try harder.

Comment: Maybe I solved your issue, see my answer. Anyway, follow the link I provided in my previous comment: it explains how to manually set the project libraries in the pro file, which you could need in a near future :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this](http://doc.qt.io/QtMQTT/index.html), there's no need to add libraries, since MQTT is a Qt module just add this line in your pro file:

```
QT += mqtt
```

To use a Qt module, it must be installed in the Qt lib directory.

First, retrieve the lib directory path executing this command from a terminal:

```
qmake -query QT_INSTALL_LIBS
```

Cd into that directory and check if a file called *Qt5Mqtt.dll* is there: if not, you must build/install the module.

To get the module source code, you can execute this git command:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtmqtt.git
```

Once you have the source files, cd into the source files directory containing the file *qtmqtt.pro* and  run these commands:

```
qmake
make
make install
```

(you may need administrator privileges for the last one).

After the commands completed successfully, you should be able to see the library in the *QT_INSTALL_LIBS* directory, and use the module in a Qt project.

In case of compilation issues, open the *qtmqtt.pro* file with creator, and try to build the library from there, then manually install (copy) it into the *QT_INSTALL_LIBS*.

Comment: the simplest soln!

Comment: Tried this, also added all .cpp and .h files to the file tree. Just to get the next error "Project ERROR: Module does not define version.
Error while parsing file /home/lucas/Proggen/qt/libs/qtmqtt-5.10/src/mqtt/mqtt.pro. Giving up.
[Inexact] Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: websockets mqtt" ..

Comment: The solution turned to be quite complicated, @MohammadKanan :(

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o who knows :)

Comment: Yeah @p-a-o-l-o - I have no idea how you could know that but it did the job.Thanks so much to help me out and wasting your time with my little problem here.

Comment: So the solution works very easy with Linux and I was able to get all my stuff running. I assume there is a similar solution for Windows? I am trying to compile my mqtt program under Windows now and cannot get the library working. Instead of "make" I tried "mingw32-make" but no success.

Comment: `mingw32-make` should be ok, just run `qmake` before and `mingw32-make install` after. If you cannot solve this, please consider making a new question out of the issue, so you can explain more freely and eloquently what you want to achieve and what you tried so far (i.e. commands you tried, complete compiler output, Windows and Qt version, etc.).

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o I tried compiling but was unsuccessful. Have the issue posted in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624425/qts-qmqtt-comiplation-issues-on-windows-10. And what I don't get it is why there is no pre-built Qt's library. I installed Qt 5.11.2 and it doesn't have the modules.

Answer (score 2):

try this step by step :

//emqttd boker

```
git clone https://github.com/emqtt/qmqtt.git
```

//Qt mqtt

```
git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qtmqtt.git
```

---

```
cd qmqtt
mkdir build
cd build
```

//Untubu

```
~/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake qmake -r ..
```

//mac Os

```
~/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/bin/qmake qmake -r ..
```

---

```
make
sudo make install
```

Done

Comment: i am getting this ERROR:

Cannot find file: qmake.
Cannot read /home/user/qtmqtt: file to open is a directory
Error processing project file: ..